# not getting child product for bundle product, using Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I am trying to get child products for a `bundle product` using **Magento 2** REST api `/V1/bundle-products/{productSku}/children`. But it always return empty array

```
 "extension_attributes": {
   "bundle_product_options": [
      {
        "option_id": 76,
        "title": "curriculum2",
        "required": true,
        "type": "checkbox",
        "position": 1,
        "sku": "f2f89c0ef1-5f0a47c874",
        "product_links": []

  } ]}
```

I have tried to get details using `product details api` too but no success.
When i login to magento admin i can see the child product in same bundle product.

Can any one help me finding what i should do?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get child products of bundle products. Make sure your child(Simple) products have **Quantity** and its **in stock**

1 ) **If you want to get only child products of bundle product then Follow below steps :**

**Url** = http://test.com/index.php/rest/V1/bundle-products/24-WG080/children

**Sku** - 24-WG080 (replace with your bundle products sku )

**Children** - it will get all children products of that bundle product.

2) **If you want to get bundle products along with its child products then Follow below steps :**

**Url** = http://test.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/24-WG080/

**Sku** - 24-WG080 (replace with your bundle products sku )

Output will be bundle products along with its child product.

**Note: Make sure your child products have Quantity and its In Stock**

Comment: sure i will look for the steps, thanks again.

Comment: links are dead.

Comment: @GordonFreeman - This is a test link not the actual link - you need to put your domain name and parameters and everything instead of test.com